# Usage of --system-header-prefix with Xcode 5.1.1 — what am I missing

Tags: xcode, clang

[Clang’s documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers) mentions the availability of a flag called `--system-header-prefix`.

The idea being that all included headers matching this prefix will be treated as system headers, and not generate warnings.

I’d like to use this flag instead of including those headers using `-isystem` instead of `-I`.

### Background

I happen to have a (new) project that depends on a couple of legacy libraries, but which itself has really strict warning settings, and treats those warnings as errors.
The result is (not too surprisingly) a project that doesn’t build because of the warnings that are generated by the headers of the included legacy–library.

The idea was to use `--system-header-prefix=legacyLib/` in Xcode’s `OTHER_CFLAGS` build setting.

If I do this, however, clang gives me the following error message:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--system-header-prefix=legacyLib/'
```

I am using Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) — i.e. the current public release.

The output of `clang --version` is

```
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I would keep the warnings as a remained that I should move away from those libraries as soon as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are referring to Clang 3.5 documentation.  In [Clang 3.4 User's Manual](http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers) this option is called `-isystem-prefix`.  The option was renamed to `--system-header-prefix` [in r204775, 2.5 months after 3.4 release](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=204775).

So you have to use `-isystem-prefix` option, but it's not explained that it's `cc1` option, so you have to use it like

```
clang -I ./nested -Xclang -isystem-prefix -Xclang legacyLib/ test.c
```

`-Xclang` is used to pass the next option to `cc1`.  By the way, I've noticed that warnings aren't suppressed if `legacyLib/` is in the same directory as `test.c`.  I don't know if it's a bug, but if you disagree with me, please [file a bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/).  The previous command works with the following directory structure

```
<working directory>
|- test.c, which has #include "legacyLib/header.h"
`- nested/
   `- legacyLib/
      `- header.h, which has warnings
```

For the future reference, Clang 3.5 supports `--system-header-prefix`, i.e. the following command works (checked with clang version 3.5.0 (trunk 207361))

```
clang -I ./nested --system-header-prefix legacyLib/ test.c
```

Comment: **Great** answer! Just waiting that the question is old enough so that I can attach a bounty to award you with.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that you value my efforts.